# Update column with reference to another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to update only the numbers inside the parentheses in the table1 below to the values from table2.

Example:

`VALUE1(1234)` should be updated to `VALUE1(1111)`

TABLE 1

```
ID   |   NAME    |  VALUE        |
----------------------------------
 1   |   Test    |  VALUE1(1234) |
 2   |   Test2   |  VALUE2(5678) |
 3   |   Test3   |  VALUE3(0987) |
 4   |   Test4   |  VALUE3(6543) |
 5   |   Test5   |  VALUE3(3210) |
```

TABLE 2

```
OLD    |   NEW    |
-------------------
 1234  |   1111   |  
 5678  |   2222   |  
 0987  |   3333   |  
 6543  |   4444   |  
 3210  |   5555   |
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a really bad database design. You shouldn't be storing things like that. Something like `value1(1234)` should be stored in two separate columns. One for `value1` and one or `1234`

Answer (score 0):

We can try using a correlated subquery for the update, combined with regex replacement logic:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 t1
SET "VALUE" = (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(t1."VALUE", '\(\d+\)', '(' || t2.NEW || ')')
               FROM TABLE2 t2
               WHERE t1."VALUE" LIKE '%(' || t2.OLD || ')%');
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Use `from` in the update:

```
update table1 t1
        set t1.value = t2.new
    from table2 t2
    where t2.old = t1.value;
```

If the value thing is actually a string, use `replace()` and `like` for the matching:

```
update table1 t1
        set t1.value = replace(t1.value, t2.old, t2.new)
    from table2 t2
    where t1.value like '%(' || t2.old || ')%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the table with the matching value from TABLE2:

```
update TABLE1
set "VALUE" = REPLACE(
  TABLE1."VALUE", 
  '(' || TABLE2."OLD" || ')', 
  '(' || TABLE2."NEW" || ')' 
)
from TABLE2
where TABLE1."VALUE" LIKE '%(' || TABLE2."OLD" || ')%';
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8gfX9PUzJ2rXx4V45nG1GY/1).
Results:

```
| ID  | NAME  | VALUE        |
| --- | ----- | ------------ |
| 1   | Test  | VALUE1(1111) |
| 2   | Test2 | VALUE2(2222) |
| 3   | Test3 | VALUE3(3333) |
| 4   | Test4 | VALUE3(4444) |
| 5   | Test5 | VALUE3(5555) |
```